# Convert string datetime in non-standard format into DATETIME on INSERT into MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a string that represents the date and time such as '30/09/2011 10:14' which is a non-standard DATETIME format. Can I reformat this to a standard DATETIME format on insert into a DATETIME field in a MySQL database table?

I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO test(lastdate) VALUES(DATE_FORMAT('30/09/2011 10:14', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))
```

The result is NULL in the lastdate DATETIME field.

Comment: you **don't** INSERT using date_format, you SELECT using a date_format

Comment: I understand that but how can I tell MySQL to insert a datetime in this format?

Comment: Have a look at STR_TO_DATE function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_to_date` to convert for your insert :

```
INSERT INTO test(lastdate) values (str_to_date('30/09/2011 10:14',"%d/%m/%Y %h:%i"))
```

`DATE_FORMAT` is for translating a date / time field to another format on `select`

Answer (score 1):

Change `date_format` to `str_to_date` and you'll be good to go.